# wrong number of input error in libsvm train

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I want to classify with linear `libsvm` function in `matlab`. I got `Wrong number of arguments` error when I run this code:

```
model1 = svmtrain(xTrain, yTrain, '-t 0');
```

my `xTrain` is a double matrix with **2612*20** dimension and my `yTrain` is a **2612*1** vector with values **-1** or **1**, Would you please help me what's wrong with this code?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you added libsvm library to the path? It seems that you are using `svmtrain` built in Matlab rather than libsvm as their names are the same. Meanwhile, the order of xTrain and yTrain is wrong, although that is not the reason you got the error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the last part of the command `'-t 0'`. According to `MATLAB`, you should have a **name-value** as the 3rd argument for this function.

> Name-Value Pair Arguments
>
> Specify optional comma-separated pairs of Name,Value arguments. Name
>   is the argument name and Value is the corresponding value. Name must
>   appear inside single quotes (' '). You can specify several name and
>   value pair arguments in any order as Name1,Value1,...,NameN,ValueN.

for instance:

```
svmStruct = svmtrain(xdata,group,'ShowPlot',true);
```

You can check [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmtrain.html#namevaluepairarguments) for correct **name-value** parameters.

In case you are using options other than standard options (that are algorithm dependent), then you should use the command `optimset` as follows:

```
my_options = optimset('param1',value1,'param2',value2,...)
```

Then you can do:

```
svmStruct = svmtrain(xdata,group,'options',my_options);
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer but I want to use libsvm toolbox as I found in examples I should use a string for libsvm options

Comment: what option do you mean. please add the edit to the question.